# Zyxel p-2602HW-1DA - LAN to WAN routing problems

Tags: router, local-area-network, url, wide-area-network, zyxel

Got a new router yesterday (due to new internet supplier) and now all my requests for my own server (local lan) is routed directly to the router instead of the server, when using dns.

Ex. 
I have a website www.mysite.org running on my server at home (local lan).
From work I can access it via www.mysite.org, which is great.
But from home (local lan) my request's for www.mysite.org gets rerouted to the routers web admin interface
My last router didn't do this.

My new router is a Zyxel P-2602HW-1DA, my old one was a LinkSys WRT-54GC V. 2.0.

There's a rather wierd WAN-LAN, WAN-WAN setup interface which I cant really comprehend yet and the docs are rather vague.

Have anyone had the same problem and can anyone guide me to a solution, would nice not write the ip address everytime i need to access the server on local lan. :).

Kind regards

Garrett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to this guy http://forum.zyxel.com/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=398 at Zyxel forums.
Quote:

Once all things are working fine . . 
if one want to reach inside servers with public dns name (e.h myservername.dyndns.org), just log via telnet (or ssh) on router.
Goto 24.8 (if a grafic interface exists) and type ip nat loopback on.
It will work until reboot.
to keep this add the command to autoexec.net file 
sys edit autoexec.net to modify
sys view autoexec.net to read it.

That was it :).

Answer (score 0):

You can be cheap an put the IP address in your hosts file on the local machine to match your domain name.

If your router is passing out nameservers with DHCP, you might be able to put it on your routers hosts file that way every IP address on your local lan will be able to go to your domain name and no editing of the local hosts table is required.

Comment: That's a brillian idea, simple and clean. Only problem is I forgot to tell I have several sites running like so:

https: SiteA

http: SiteB
https: SiteB

http: SiteC

So unless you know of a way to specify port numbers/protocols in the hosts file, i don't know how to get around it?

Kind regards

Comment: I keep thinking that if I could just ensure that all my dns requests where route out to the WAN then it would all work, but for some reason my router(or my IIS) reroutes me to local lan, as if IT was the dns server.